# Windows 10 mobile text tone

Tags: insider-preview, ringtone

Why when I try to assign a different text tone to one of my contacts Windows 10 mobile asks me: "Search for app in the Store?"

I'm using build: 10586.107

Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me on build 10586.494. Can you try updating your phone? The latest public build should be 10586.420, released about a month ago (whereas the build you're using is almost 5 months old).

Comment: I'm using Nokia 630 and left out from updates 5 months ago. I guess I need a new Windows Phone...

Answer (score 1):

As @Indrek said it works fine for me too in build 10586.494. This build is available for public.

So this must be a bug that is fixed in update. Have you tried using Preview release ring in the Insider app? This may work for you. If not there is no way to solve it as your phone cannot be updated.